# Alternatives to important in CSS?

Tags: html, css

If I have a css file, mystyle.css:

```
body {
font-family: OpenSans, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
}

.news {
width: 800px;
background-color: #99EBFF;
}
```

but I wanted to override it for a specific part of the site for  (in another CSS file, for example, cms-news-pages.css), e.g.:

```
.news {
padding: 2.5px;
width: 600px;
background-color: #FFE6B3 !important;
}
```

what would be a preferable alternative to !important for a class without getting into too much code spaghetti?

If anyone could advise me I'd be grateful for this, trying to make cleaner CSS coding.

Comment: CSS prioritises by specificity so you could just do ```body .news {...}``` and it should override just ```.news``` also make sure to include your custom css file after the default one

Comment: a solution is to put your new CSS code underr the old one and it gets overwritten its called CASCADING syle sheet. it goes from top to bottom

Comment: if you just want a specific news container to be different, give it an id and style the id - it will override the class (and is more efficient than adding a parent selector)

Comment: @Pete yea, typo

Comment: You're right that `!important` is like a cheat-mode for CSS and it's not really advisable to use it in production.

Normally the tools available for you to enable style overrides are:

 - specificity
 - the cascade order

If you rely on the cascade order too much things can get difficult to debug, so in this situation, I'd use specificity.

Comment: **Working Example:**

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-css -->

    .news {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: #99EBFF;
    }

    .news.news-page {
    padding: 2.5px;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #FFE6B3 !important;
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div class="news">
    <h2>News</h2>
    <p>This is the news.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="news news-page">
    <h2>News on News Page</h2>
    <p>This is the news on a dedicated news page.</p>
    </div>

<!-- end snippet -->

Answer (score 2):

Try to give more prefrence using parent selectors

Suppose `.news` has parent with classname `.news-container`

Then you can use

```
.news-container .news {
    background-color: #FFE6B3;
}
```

This will override css property of the `.news`.